# Writing document to CouchDB using angular $http with authentication

Tags: angularjs, curl, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB in a mobile app to synchronize the local database instance with a remote one. I need to add the `_security` document to the database. I tried adding the `_security` to the local PouchDB database, but it doesn't allow documents starting with _ (design documents) to be added/edited. Because the `_security` document is not needed in the local database, I thought I could just add it to the remote database by sending a HTTP PUT request.

With cUrl I can add the `_security` document with this command:

```
curl -X PUT http://dbadmin:'password'@IP.ADDR:5984/databasename/_security -d '{"admins":{"names":["myuser"], "roles":[]}, "readers":{"names":[],"roles":["myreaders"]}}'
```

And it works fine. There is something wrong though with my Angular $http method. I use this code:

```
$http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: "http://dbadmin:password@IP.ADDR:5984/databasename/_security",
      data: JSON.stringify({_id: '_security', admins: {names: ['"' + userID + '"'], roles: []}, readers: {names: [], roles: ['"myreaders"']}})
  });
```

And I get this error: `Error: Access to restricted URI denied`

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Any other suggestions on how to write the `security` document, i.e. not using $http are also welcome. I had a look at: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3529 and the pages it links to, but couldn't find a solution that works for me. I had a look at the `pouchdb-security` plugin, but would prefer not having to use a plugin just to write the `_security` document and also couldn't find any documentation about that plugin on the plugin's project page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-security).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you wanted to hear, but if you are PUTing a `_security` document from a client, then you are probably doing something very wrong. Giving all of your users full admin privileges to your CouchDB is a recipe for disaster.

This is why PouchDB does not make it easy for you to PUT the `_security` doc. :)

As for the "Access to restricted URI" error itself, it is probably because you did not enable CORS on CouchDB: https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb

Comment: I don't think I'm doing anything wrong. If you look at the github link I posted, there was a discussion about just this. PouchDB developers are participating in that discussion and no one mentioned there, that there is something wrong with putting/adding the _security document. I do not give users full admin privileges, why do you assume I do? I login as admin to create the database for the user (using pouchdb-authentication [did you write that?). I also don't think it is a CORS issue, because I installed the CORS CouchDB plugin and if I disable security (admin party) database syncing works.

Comment: Sorry, I re-read the Github issue, and yeah I wrote pouchdb-authentication. The conversation in that issue was why PouchDB itself doesn't allow you to put the _security document, and the discussion from the developers was whether we should expose a generic AJAX wrapper (`db.request`), which actually we do now, although we call it [extras/api](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#extras). In general, though, you can use any AJAX method (such as `$http`) to accomplish what you want. I still don't recommend it, because yes, you need admin rights to PUT the `_security` doc.

Answer (score 0):

I can try now but I think your problem come from the _id data you send with your request:

```
_id: '_security'
```

Id of the document is already on the URL ("http://dbadmin:password@IP.ADDR:5984/databasename/_security",) so you juste have to send data like:

```
$http({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: "http://dbadmin:password@IP.ADDR:5984/databasename/_security",
  data: JSON.stringify({admins: {names: ['"' + userID + '"'], roles: []}, readers: {names: [], roles: ['"myreaders"']}})
  });
```